Power analysis for a goodness-of-fit test over multivariate categorical distribution
I have some data where each datapoint is described by N categorical variables. I do not know a priori whether these variables are independent from each other (but to an extreme, I may assume it), e.g.,
               Size    Shape    Color  ...   CatN
datapoint1     Big      Round    Red    ...   A
datapoint2     Big      Square   Blue   ...   B
datapoint3     Medium   Round    Blue   ...   C
...            ...      ...      ...    ...   ...
datapointM     Small    Oval     Green  ...   B

I need to run power analysis to find the sample size necessary to run a "goodness-of-fit" test to check whether a sample does fit the original (multivariate categorical) distribution (for a given power and alpha).
My questions are:

Is this possible?
If yes, which test would correspond to a goodness-of-fit test for such a distribution (if not the goodness-of-fit test itself, adapted to the multivariate scenario)?
How do I fit it into the power analysis framework?

NOTE: I know the name "multivariate categorical distribution" may not be entirely correct in this case, as there are nuances in the "multivariate" term, but I couldn't find a precise name in the literature for my case – which is actually very frequent, except from this one. If you have better references for this, I'll be happy to correct my question.
